# Import multiple .txt files and merging them

Tags: r, time-series

There are around 3k .txt files, comma separated with equal structure and no col names.
e.g. 08/15/2018,11.84,11.84,11.74,11.743,27407  ///

I only need col1 (date) and col 5 (11.743) and would like to import all those vectores with the name of the .txt file assigned (AAAU.txt -> AAAU vector). In a second step I would like to merge them to a matrix, with all the possible dates in rows and colums with .txt filename and col5 value for each date.

I tried using readr, but I was unable to include the information of the filename, thus I cannot proceed.

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but I think this will work for you.  You can use list.files() to pull in all file names into a variable, then read each one individually and append it to a new data frame with either rbind() or cbind()

```
setwd("C:/your_favorite_directory/")
fnames <- list.files()
csv <- lapply(fnames, read.csv)
result <- do.call(rbind, csv)

# grab a subset of the fields you need 
df <- subset(result, select = c(a, e))

#then write your final file
write.table(df,"AllFiles.txt",sep=",")
```

Also, the '-' sign indicates dropping variables. Make sure the variable names would NOT be specified in quotes when using subset() function.

```
df = subset(mydata, select = -c(b,c,d) )
```